# Chinese narrative style in Cordwainer Smith stories

Tags: short-stories, literary-analysis, cordwainer-smith

I've read several times that Cordwainer Smith used traditional Chinese narrative styles in some of his stories. But I've never seen any specifics. Smith's [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordwainer_Smith#Science_fiction_style) offers more detail than most of these assertions:

> Smith's stories are unusual, sometimes being written in narrative styles closer to traditional Chinese stories than to most English-language fiction, as well as reminiscent of the [Japanese] Genji tales of Lady Murasaki.

What are these styles and how do they relate to Smith's prose? The best answer will give at least one example of a story and relate it to a traditional narrative style, hopefully in such a way as to make it clear how the style differs from that of non-Chinese narratives.

Comment: Have you read "The rediscovery of Cathay: Chinese elements in Cordwainer Smith's science fiction" by Danny J. Han-Chang Lin?  This tries to give solid evidence for the Chinese influences (rather than just stating that the influences exist). I believe you can view the text at http://danjalin.blogspot.com/2007/11/rediscovery-of-cathay-chinese-elements_16.html

Comment: Indeed I have not! Thank you very much.

Comment: Lin's article could be used as the basis for an answer, as he covers everything that I asked for. Would you like to write one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the OP notes, it is frequently asserted that [Cordwainer Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordwainer_Smith) (the pseudonym used by Paul Linebarger) wrote using a traditional Chinese narrative style, and certainly it is true that his stories have a very different “flavour” to typical SF stories. Given that Linebarger was a noted scholar in Far Eastern studies this is probably not surprising. In examining exactly how Chinese narrative style can be seen in his stories, I am largely guided by an excellent article “The rediscovery of Cathay: Chinese elements in Cordwainer Smith's science fiction" by Danny Lin, available at his [blog](https://danjalin.blogspot.com/2007/11/rediscovery-of-cathay-chinese-elements_16.html) where a far more detailed and expert analysis is given.

It is important to note that the typical Chinese narrative structure arises from an oral tradition, in which stories were recounted by professional storytellers in public spaces like streetmarkets. Clearly this is a very different way of telling a story than by reading from a printed page, and is the fundamental reason for many of the elements in these narratives that may seem unusual. To assist them, storytellers follow a set of more-or-less codified rules called 話本 [Hua Ben](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huaben) – "the book for storytelling", or "the basis for storytelling".

A typical story in this form is formed of five parts:

1. The opening. This is usually a verse or poem about the topic, or an allegory of the main story.
2. 入話 Ru Hua (entering the story). This introduces the background and the meaning of the opening verse, as well as providing some comments (“This is sure to be interesting - you’ll never have heard a story like this before!”) to try and attract people to come and listen,
3. 頭回 Tou Hui. This is a retelling of some shorter or simpler stories, independent to the main one, but generally related to it in some way. What is the point of this? In the public space this gives an opportunity for a larger group of people to gather. The early birds can listen to this and be amused, while the latecomers are settling in.
4. The main body.
5. The ending, often another short verse acts as a conclusion.

Let’s look as an example at the *[Ballad of Lost C’Mell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Lost_C%27Mell)*, available at [Project Gutenberg](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/smithcordwainer-balladoflostcmell/smithcordwainer-balladoflostcmell-00-h.html).

1. It opens with a verse:

> She got the which of the what-she-did,
>
> Hid the bell with a blot, she did,
>
> But she fell in love with a hominid.
>
> Where is the which of the what-she-did?

(Smith regarded himself as “one of the most minor of the minor poets of America”, but nonetheless he follows tradition and includes verses in his stories. This is traditional in Chinese literature to make the storyteller seem more erudite.)

2. There is then a brief introduction to the characters and location, containing the line “It had never happened before, and it is sure never to happen again” - a line designed for a storyteller to draw attention to what he is telling. There is another excellent example of the storyteller whipping up interest in Smith’s *[The Crime and the Glory of Commander Suzdal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crime_and_the_Glory_of_Commander_Suzdal)*:

> Do not read this story: turn the page quickly. The story may upset
> you. Anyhow, you probably know it already. It is a very disturbing
> story. Everyone knows it. The glory and the crime of Commander Suzdal
> have been told in a thousand different ways. Don't let yourself
> realize that the story is the truth.
>
> It isn't. Not at all. There's not a bit of truth to it. There is no
> such planet as Arachosia, no such people as klopts, no such world as
> Catland. There are all just imaginary, they didn't happen, forget
> about it, go away and read something else.

The warning of not reading further of course is to encourage the reader to pay more attention.

3. Lin notes “It is almost impossible for writers to compose Tou Hui in modern stories published in the media like science fiction magazine”, there being little motivation to include a short(er) story within another story. Accordingly in *The Ballad of Lost C’Mell*, and in most of Smith's stories, there is no Tou Hui. Smith does not actually follow the conventions of this genre with complete strictness (see also the ending).
4. The main part of the story.  Like a story told by a traditional storyteller, the audience is addressed in a first person tone, by an omniscient third-person narrator. Smith rarely uses standard storytelling phrases like “Here the story splits into two parts”, or “Now we return back to our main characters”, but he does have a habit of using explanations in parentheses, like a storyteller making an aside to the crowd. In the *[Dead Lady of Clown Town](http://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/ebooks/smithcordwainer-deadladyofclowntown/smithcordwainer-deadladyofclowntown-00-h.html)* for example:

> The supervisor sighed hopefully. He was young. "Guess it doesn't
> matter," he thought, picked up his guitar.
>
> *(Thirty-seven years later, he found out that it did matter. The Lady
> Goroke herself, one of the Chiefs of the Instrumentality, sent a
> Subchief of he Instrumentality to find out who had caused D'joan.
> ...... He was not punished otherwise, but the Lady Goroke commanded
> that those memories be left in his mind for so long as he might live.)*
>
> The man picked up his guitar, but the machine went on about its work.

5. Here again Smith usually deviates from the strict rules of providing a closing verse, and usually provides a more Westernised conclusion. *The Ballad of Lost C'Mell*, for example, concludes:

> I am dying. I must know. Did she love me?
>
> "She went on without you, so much did she love you. She let you go,
> for your sake, not for hers. She really loved you. More than death.
> More than life. More than time. You will never be apart."
>
> Never apart?
>
> "Not, not in the memory of man," said the voice, and was then still.
>
> Jestocost lay back on his pillow and waited for the day to end.

Comment: Great answer, and a wonderful introduction to Chinese stories as well as an explanation of Chinese narrative in Cordwainer Smith's stories. Thank you so much!